# Recommended online software for Euler method/ODEs

Tags: software, differential-equations

Solving a first order ODE with the Euler method is simple enough, if the student is to do it for a few rounds, however for anything substantial a programmable calculator or access to a programming language will be required. I see a number of web apps that bypass such requirements. If you have used them in your classes which one do you prefer and why?

So here we are solving dy/dx=f(x,y), with a given (x0,y0), and step-size h. The output will be (x_i,y_i), for i from 0 to N, and perhaps an error estimate,  etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the purpose of "bypassing" the usage of a programming language. If the students don't know enough programming to implement a simple numerical algortihm, then what's the point in teaching them such numerical algorithms? Could you elaborate?

Comment: I can't speak to whether this is the case here, but Euler's method is tested on the AP Calculus BC exam, and there's so much content (and such high stakes) on that exam that it's not really feasible to spend time covering things like programming that are outside the standard syllabus. https://apcentral.collegeboard.org/media/pdf/ap-calculus-ab-and-bc-course-and-exam-description.pdf

Comment: @JochenGlueck I have attempted to incorporate MatLab. But first you need to help them download it, then go through giving instructions on setting up files and scripts and running it etc. Next  you notice you have spent many class periods on it with mixed results. I'd rather use single-use ready-made online apps.

Answer (score 4):

This is the best one that I've come across: https://www.geogebra.org/m/NUeFjm9J

[image: Geogebra Euler Estimator]

Answer (score 1):

Most students know how to use a spreadsheet like EXEl and it's very easy to do implement euler with it . I did it with my high school kids.